# Oracle SQL setting single unique character

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, ora-04091

I am having trouble with creating a table in oracle SQL.

I was looking to have a column called DEFAULTRULE. Only 1 row in this column can be '1' at any given time. So for example

```
ID    DEFAULTRULE
1     0
2     0
3     1
```

If I was to update ID 2 to have default rule = 1 then it would either set ID 3 default rule to 0

or

throw an error (I don't really mind as long as there is only one '1')

I have tried to create triggers to do both but keep getting the

> ORA-04091 table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.

2 of my attempts:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECKDEFAULTRULE
  BEFORE UPDATE ON BUSINESS_RULE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
v_count NUMBER(1);
BEGIN 
  IF :NEW.DEFAULTRULE = 1 THEN
      SELECT COUNT(DEFAULTRULE)INTO v_count FROM BUSINESS_RULE WHERE DEFAULTRULE = 1;
      IF v_count != 0 THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'BUSINESS_RULE already has a default rule. Please set this to 0 and try again');
      END IF;  
   END IF;
END;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECKDEFAULTRULE
BEFORE UPDATE ON BUSINESS_RULE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF :new.DEFAULTRULE = 1 THEN
   UPDATE BUSINESS_RULE
   SET    DEFAULTRULE = 0;
   WHERE  DEFAULTRULE = 1; 
END IF;
END checkDefaultForOne;
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a trigger.

Use an expression based unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX someindex ON sometable( 
  CASE WHEN DEFAULTRULE = 1
       THEN 1
  END
  );
```

See this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2431a

It allows for insetring many DEFAULTRULE != 1, but only one DEFAULTRULE = 1

try to append additional `INSERT INTO sometable VALUES( 1,1);` in this demo and you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you kordirko. Really appreciate the help and the insanely fast response! 
I was just about to update this after finding: 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/how-to-implement-a-default-flag-that-can-only-be-set-on-a-single-row

Didn't think anyone would have reply so fast! 
This is working like a charm :D